# Silverlight DataGrid BeginEdit method causes CellEditEnded event

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I have a requirement that users should be able to click on an (editable) cell in a grid, and it goes into edit-mode immediately rather than having to double-click on press F2. To do this I added a behavior:

```
public class AutomaticallyEditGridBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        if (AssociatedObject.IsReadOnly)
        {
            return;
        }

        AssociatedObject.CurrentCellChanged += OnCurrentCellChanged;
    }

    private void OnCurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Check our column is not readonly first
        if (AssociatedObject.CurrentColumn.IsReadOnly)
        {
            return;
        }

        AssociatedObject.BeginEdit();
    }
}
```

I also have some logic for when the cell has been edited, so I added another behavior:

```
public class CellEditEndedBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.CellEditEnded += CellEditEnded;
    }

    private void CellEditEnded(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.EditAction != DataGridEditAction.Commit)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (AssociatedObject.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Some processing and logic to get next editable item

        // Set the focus to the next item and begin editing
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItem = nextEditableItem;
        AssociatedObject.CurrentColumn = e.Column;
        AssociatedObject.Focus();
        AssociatedObject.BeginEdit();
    }
}
```

I find that when I click on a cell, the first behavior runs, but before there is a chance to edit that cell the CellEditEnded event has fired. Therefore, the focus moves to the next object and not the cell that was just clicked on.

Why is this event firing before the cell has actually been edited? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you combine this into a single behavior and just check to see if you just started the edit and if so ignore the commit?

Comment: I really wanted to keep the behaviors separate as I will be using the AutomaticallyEditGridBehavior in several grids, but the CellEditEndedBehavior is specific to just one of my grids.

Comment: Just add a property to enable the CellEditEndedBehavior. AutoMoveNext=true on the ones where you need it.

Comment: This is probably what I'll do. It doesn't explain why this is happening though - it's more of a workaround.